# Clicks going to background window in Adobe AIR app on OS X High Sierra

Tags: air, macos-sierra

We have a fairly large AIR desktop application (captive AIR, using Runtime version 21).

Recently our QA have confirmed and reproduced an odd report by a Mac user:

When the app is in full screen, running on OS X High Sierra, then some clicks on the main user interface go through to whatever application is running behind the window. Whatever background window has been clicked, it will jump to the front and the click is processed, e.g. if the click was sent to a Finder window and happened to be in the location of a favorites folder, that folder will be opened as if you clicked it when the Finder window was open.

If no window is behind our app at the click location, the desktop will receive focus.

This is not consistent and even clicks in the same spot (as much as one can hit the same pixel twice) sometimes go to the background window and sometimes end up, as expected, in our window.

I know that this sound weird but it's been verified both by our QA and by me and another developer working on different machines.

Ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question after some trial and error:
Upgrading to AIR SDK 28 solved the problem.
Bonus tip: Avoid Adobe AIR. Great technology, zero support, dead forums.

Comment: The list of problems in High Sierra is not only limited to Adobe AIR. There already a list of application in our organisation which are NOT Adobe AIR and runs through a tons of problem, while running on High Sierra. So, you can bet it's a new field to explore for every development house (thanks to this OS' restrictions/limitations/bugs).